# How do I implement self-referencing hreflang tags on a translated website?

Tags: wordpress, hreflang, translation

We're currently using HREFLANG plugin on my WordPress site, but it doesn't have tags for all the countries we need, so we also use the WPML plugin, however this plugin won't let you edit the `hreflang` tags.

There are my few language directories which I created through this plugin:

- `https://example.com/en/`
- `https://example.com/de/`
- `https://example.com/fr/`
- `https://example.com/it/`
- `https://example.com/es/`

Ahrefs audit report says that my site has: `"errors with no return tags and conflicting hreflang and rel=canonical"`

This is not a separate directory that I can access with different WordPress login and solve this issue. In this case, what is the method I can use to solve this issue?

When I check source code of this site I found this code automatically added by plugin:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://example.com/en/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="https://example.com/de/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr" href="https://example.com/fr/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="it" href="https://example.com/it/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="https://example.com/es/" />
```

Are there any problems with this code, and if so, how can I solve them?

Comment: There are also other hreflang tag: `<!-- / HREFLANG Tags by DCGWS Version 2.0.0 -->
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.xometry.com/" hreflang="en-CA" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.xometry.com/" hreflang="en-US" />
<!-- / HREFLANG Tags by DCGWS -->`.  Do you know where those are coming from?

Comment: Where do you find them? I don't see any of this in the source code.

Comment: They are generated through DCGWS HREFLANG plugin. If I remove this .com hreflang or pointing .com domain to .eu domain this issue will be solved?

Comment: I know that those two hreflang tags are not correct while the ones that you posted in your question look reasonable to me.

Comment: This two are conflicting with each other and I did not add hreflang on the xometry.com domain. If you are go to .com domain then you'll see there is no hreflang tag. If I fix these issue then it will be okay? What is your thought about it?

Comment: By the way! I got your LinkedIn and Instagram also YouTube. 

Comment: Those hreflangs are in the source code for your /en/ homepage: `view-source:https://xometry.eu/en/` You should remove them.  I'm not sure if it will totally solve the problem, but it is a step in the right direction.